# How to get all documentsID from this class

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

i have this method inside this class, and i want to call this method in a screen and get all IDs inside a map().

```
final databaseReference = Firestore.instance;

class CompanyServices {
  static CollectionReference get companies =>
      databaseReference.collection('companies');

  static getDocumentID() async {
    final QuerySnapshot result = await companies.getDocuments();
    final List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = result.documents;

    documents.forEach((data) {
      print(data.documentID);
    });
  }
}
```

and screen i'm calling this way:

`CompanyServices.getDocumentID()`

and i've this error:
`type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'`

How  do i call that method get all documentsID inside a map?

Thx in advance.

Comment: `getDocumentID` does not return anything and does not have any return type. Also, the return type of `async` methods will be `Future<something>` but since you are missing the return type, Dart will just assume it is dynamic (can be anything) and therefor `Future<dynamic>`.

Comment: Hey, you're right, theres no return statement :/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your problem is in the `DocumentSnapshot` since when you do for each loop the `data` is of type `DocumentSnapshot` , and when u do `data.documentID` it seems that this field is not a string but instead is a Future, you can try doing `await data.documentID.toString()` inside your print but I wouldn't really recommend it as I'm unaware of the data shape but it might work

Answer (score 0):

So... Thank you @Abbas.M and @julemand101 for your insights.
You were my psychologist of code :P

Answering my own question:
I was trying to get a Future without .then and all that stuff and waiting to get a response before it arrive... I forgot my background with promises in JS.

I got working, converting all my screen stateless to statefull and fetch that data, store it into a state var and with it, my widget is rebuilt and i have that var anytime i want.

Thank you for your support and answers.

Can i vote both of your answers? :P